# Cannot mount any file system/USB stick with Nautilus side bar after changing UID of my user

Tags: usb, nautilus, mount, permissions, users

There are a lot of answers in here that describe how to change a user's UID. This is necessary to match it to my NAS and to ease NFS mounts and permissions.

BUT: I had to do this on Ubuntu 13.04 and after I changed my user's UID, I cannot mount ANY devices anymore in Nautilus side bar.
In Nautilus when I click on a different file system that is not mounted or insert a USB stick, I get the error message: (in German)

"Dieser Ort konnte nicht angezeigt werden" and then (I translate):
"You don't have the required permissions to see the contents of ad390f97.........."

This is a DIRECT implication I got right after changing the UID and rebooting. So there must be something wrong in Nautilus that does not like changing of UIDs!

What is that? I need to get this fixed!

Answer (score 1):

About an hour ago, I had the same problem. I changed my UID, logged out 
and logged in. I stuck an external drive in the USB port and saw that it was mounted.

When I clicked on the drive icon on the Desktop, UBUNTU said that it doesn't know how to open the file.

You are lucky since the error message lead you directly to the problem.I am using 
XUBUNTU 14.04, since I can't stand Gnome 3 and Unity. XFCE could be the reason for the different error message.

Anyway, after about an hour of googling and trying things with mime type handlers etc. I decided to see under which user UBUNTU was mounting the drive. It was 'root'. The external volumes are mounted under the folder /media/${USER}. In my case /media/${USER} had the owner:group root:root.

I changed it to

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER}
```

I restarted. Logged in and now it is working.

I hope it helps.